# Multivariable limit - is my calculation correct? ? ?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to prove the following limit does not exist:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0^+,0^+)} \frac{\ln(1-\sqrt{xy})}{x^2+y^2}
$$

what I did was checking the following two paths:

1. $(x,y)=(t,t), t\to 0^+$  which leads to $-\infty$.
2. $(x,y)=(t,0)$ which leads to $0$.

My question is:
is it correct to choose a path like $(x,y)=(t,0), t \to 0^+$ when I need $(x,y)\to (0^+,0^+)$ ? If not, then how can I prove the following limit does not exist?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I think that's right. If the limit exists it must be the same for all possible directions. So that's a good way to prove that a limit doesn't exist.

Comment: If you use $(x,y)=(t,0)$ then the second coordinate is not approaching $0$ from above, whereas the limit is as $(x,y) \to (0^+,0^+).$ Maybe try $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$ or similar.

Comment: @coffeemath : is such a path ($(x,y)=(t,0)$) legitimate if the limit was at $(0,0)$ and not $(0^+, 0^+) $ ? 

Thanks

Comment: Genuin... Yes if it said just $x,y$ each approaching zero, the path would work.

Comment: @coffeemath: Thank  you very much. In this case, what different path do you suggest ? If I substitute $(t,t^3)$ I get again $-\infty$ as the limit (but I want a path that will give me a different result.). Will you please help me ? Thanks a lot

Comment: You have already the path $(t,t)$ leading to the limit being $-\infty$ So depending on what is meant for a limit to exist, you may be already finished. However if some text *does* allow $- \infty$ as the value of a limit, you would have to either get another path going to something else, or show you always get $-\infty$ Question for you--- does your course allow $-\infty$ as the value of a limit? If it does, I'll try to see...

Comment: @coffeemath: I think I have an answer : 
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0^+,0^+)} \frac{\ln(1-\sqrt{xy})}{x^2+y^2}= \lim_{(x,y)\to (0^+,0^+)} \overbrace{\frac{\ln(1-\sqrt{xy})}{xy}}^{\to -\infty} \overbrace{ \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} } ^\text{No Limit}
$$
and the first term goes to $-\infty$ and the second term has no limit. So, this has no limit, regardless of whether or not $-\infty$ is considered an "existing" limit or not. What do you think? Thank you very much !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32821/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-genuinlygenius).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$f(x,y)=\frac{\ln(1-\sqrt{xy})}{x^2+y^2}
$$
and consider the paths of the form $(x,y)=(t,a^2t^3)$ with $a>0$ a fixed real parameter. Then for each $t>0$ the point on the path has positive $x,y$ and the value of $f$ is
$$\frac{\ln(1-at^2)}{t^2+a^4t^6}.$$
Here as $t \to 0^+$ the numerator and denominator each tend to zero, making LHopital OK to apply, getting the derivative ratio, after some algebra, to be
$$-a \cdot \frac{1}{1-at^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+3a^4t^4}.$$
Now as $t \to 0^+$ the latter tends to $-a.$ Thus we have a family of paths for which the value of $f$ tends to any number $-a$ with $a>0$ so there cannot be a limit of $f$ as $x,y$ each approach $0$ through positive values.

Comment: Thanks ! It looks very good. But, I still can't understand what is wrong with my solution (which does not produce any finite limit):
Is it correc that $\lim_{0^+} \frac{\ln (1-\sqrt{t})}{t}=-\infty$? Is it also correct that $\lim_{(0^+,0^+)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ has no limit ? If so , then in particular this shows that we can produce $\infty$ and $-\infty$ limits, right? So the limit does not exist. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @genuinlygenius There is no possibility to produce a limit of $+\infty$ because the value of $\ln(1-\sqrt{xy})$ is negative when $x,y>0$ and $\sqrt{xy}<1.$ Note that the latter must hold in order that $\ln(1-\sqrt{xy})$ be defined, because the domain of $\ln(u)$ is $u>0.$ And since the log term is negative and one is dividing by the positive $x^2+y^2$ the overall fraction is negative.

Comment: @genuinlygenius Maybe this will clear up my last comment. Given that $(x,y) \to (0^+,0^+),$ the value of $\sqrt{xy}$ will be positive and approach zero from above. So $1-\sqrt{xy}$ will be positive and approach $1$ from *below*. Now note that for  $u \in (0,1)$ we have $\ln(u)<0.$ Then since it is divided by the positive number $x^2+y^2$ the result will always be negative during the approach $(x,y) \to (0^+,0^+).$

Comment: You are completely right. An alternative way would be to write:
$=\frac{ln(1-\sqrt{xy})}{-\sqrt{xy}} \frac{-\sqrt{xy}}{x^2+y^2}$ . The first term in the product converges to -1 (right?), while the second does not exist (for example by taking $y=x, y=x^3$ which gives two different limits. What do you think about this way? 

Thank you very much for your helpful explanation! (I will accept your answer in a few moments. I am afraid that once I will accept it , you will no longer answer me :) )

Comment: Actually $\ln(1-t)/(-t)$ converges to $+1.$ The second term can only be negative. And note that the second term can go to any value $-a$ [with $a>0$] along the same path $(t,a^2t^3)$ as looked at in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much . !!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32863/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-genuinlygenius).